# inconsistence between mapper and randint python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to understand why the output of the following python code shows two lists.

Removing `mapper` module, the output is as expected.

**MWE**

```
from random import randint
import mapper as mp

x=[randint(0,9) for p in range(0,10)]
print(x)
```

**output**

```
[5, 7, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 4, 6]
[0, 2, 7, 6, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your script file is not named `mapper.py`. Otherwise, importing the `mapper` will load the script twice causing print different random number sequences twice.

You should also make sure there's no `mapper.pyc` remain.

Comment: Ohhh, I never could imagine that. Thanks a lot.